# Android: menu in action bar

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar

i have problem putting the menu there, in the upper right corner:

android manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="it.mio.app"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
<application android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light">
    <activity android:name=".Lista_preventivi"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Java:

```
public class Lista_preventivi extends Activity{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.lista_preventivi);
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

menu xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/action_settings" />
</menu>
```

all works, but the menu appear only if i click the physical button on my phone, and it appear at the bottom like a normal menu.

ho can i have the icon menu in the upper right action bar, and show the menu there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The theme which your are applying to the application is android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light". it doesn't have an actionbar.

Change it to something which has an action bar like,

- Theme.Sherlock.Light (Need to add ABS library)
- Theme.Holo.Light

The code is just fine.

Comment: yes, it works thanks. but now the button for show the menu is directly the Settings item :-|

Comment: if you want it to be visible always, then set android:showAsAction="always"

Comment: no, i mean: i want a button in the upper right, like this 3 dots: http://andkamau.files.wordpress.com/2011/07/google-plus-action-bar-quick-actions-copy.png
and when i click it, i show the menu (which now have only one item)

Comment: take a look at this link: http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/1267. it might help. what u are trying to achieve can be done using overflow menu itself. but, if there multiple buttons similar to what you want now, then creating a drop down list menu is the choice you have got.

Comment: i was thinking that was a new option in android sdk, now i think is a coding one.

Answer (score 0):

Add:
`android:showAsAction="always"` in your manifest file
If your sdk version is >3.0 .Else you have no other option other than implementing Sherlock Home Api.

Comment: you can edit R.menu file to modify the menu content. As you have described.