# Unable to see menu in action bar Android

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar

i have problem putting the menu  in the upper right corner. even i checked this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17401188/android-menu-in-action-bar). but not worked.

- i have tried with `android:showAsAction="always"`even tried with more then  `6 SDK version` but not worked .

manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.Test"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"
android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

items.xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:id="@+id/phone"
    android:title="@string/phone"
    android:icon="@drawable/phone"
    android:showAsAction="always"
/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/computer"
    android:title="@string/computer"
    android:icon="@drawable/computer"

/></menu>
```

Java:-

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.items, menu);
    //inflater.inflate(R.menu.items, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.phone:
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You selected Phone", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        case R.id.computer:
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You selected Computer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }
    return true;

}
}
```

.
please suggest . any suggestion are welcome . Thanks

Comment: Where is the inflation code?

Comment: @NickCardoso i have edited my blog . please check . all works, but the menu appear only if i click the physical button on my phone, and it appear at the bottom like a normal menu.

Comment: are you using appCompat_v7?

Comment: no appCompat_v4 .even i tried without that but not worked

Comment: @Anand Dwivedi: May I know OS version of device u checked?

Comment: @kevz v4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich). and even i tried on Emulator and mobile as well but not working .but the menu appear only if i click the physical button on my phone, and it appear at the bottom like a normal menu.

Comment: @Anand Dwivedi: u can check my answer...

Comment: What does " it appear at the bottom like a normal menu." mean? What normal menu's appear at the bottom? What theme are you sing? Does the action bar itself show?

Comment: meanse if i click on menu option in emulator  then it appear

Answer (score -1):

Solution as below-

1. In build.gradle(Module:app) add appcompat dependency

   ```
   dependencies {
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
   // ... other dependencies
   }
   ```
2. change

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity
   ```

to

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity.
```

3. change your menu.xml file as below

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
   <item
       android:id="@+id/phone"
       android:title="@string/phone"
       android:icon="@drawable/phone"
       app:showAsAction="always" />

      <item
      android:id="@+id/computer"
      android:title="@string/computer"
      android:icon="@drawable/computer" />

   </menu>
   ```

Comment: @Anand Dwivedi: woah a downvote I thought it'll be good clear stuff about it. Anyways I'd like u to test it in Kitkat version device and see it urself.

Comment: i haven't give down vote . even i tried with your example as well

Comment: This too is only showing the same as the OP has already done rather than address the problem. You should comment rather than put an answer if what you are writing isn't actually an answer to the question. 'ur' isn't a word.

Comment: @Nick Cardoso: Thanks for being kind :). I've addressed the issue and provided a solution.

Comment: @Anand Dwivedi: Make above change in ur app.